Google Static Map API - Large URL for GET request
I have this program that monitors an API. the API is polled each couple of seconds and it might return some array of cities. I translate these cities, each one, to coordinates and I might have a lng and lat, or a polygon which is a set of lat and lngs.
I'm using a NodeJS process to poll that API and when the code triggers the data aggregation and map generation process, I'm building up an array of coords and send a GET request to the google static map api with the data as query params and gets back an image of a map with markers / polygons.
The problem is whenever the cities array I get is big enough I might encounter an aggregated URL with 30k chars, it is not possible to send it via GET as the max limit I've encountered is around 8k chars for Apachi web servers, therefore the request fails.
How can I improve the process of generating a map using many lng and lats to get polygons and markers on map?

The documentation states a few things about URLs.

Maps Static API URLs are restricted to 16384 characters in size. In practice, you will probably not have need for URLs longer than this, unless you produce complicated maps with a high number of markers and paths.

And

Instead of a series of locations, you may instead declare a path as an encoded polyline by using the enc: prefix within the location declaration of the path.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility?hl=en
This page says that

This utility uses the Maps JavaScript API. Specifically, encoding and decoding of paths are handled by the static methods encodePath() and decodePath() in the google.maps.geometry.encoding namespace.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?hl=en#Encoding for the related documentation.
This is part of the Geometry Library from the Javascript API which is not available as a web service, but I see there are at least a couple of Node packages that implement it:

https://github.com/mapbox/polyline
https://github.com/aasatech/geometry-library

